# Exchange Server distribution lists functionality on a Linux-based web host?

Tags: linux, php, distribution-lists, web-applications

I'm trying to figure out a way to centrally manage staff distribution lists for an organisation. There are many people that will want to send emails to these lists and we're currently all maintaining our own versions. This is a start-up charity with no budget so I'm wondering if there is something available that might run on their webserver (cPanel). A couple of hours of Google foo is turning up nothing obvious.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please check following steps to do it in cpanel itself:

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/MailingLists
http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/ImportAddresses
http://www.4webhelp.net/tutorials/misc/cpanel3.php

Answer (score 0):

[mailman](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/index.html) is a good mailing list manager for linux, and it looks like it integrates with cpanel (based on a very quick google search :)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'm aware of mailman but it doesn't fit here because these aren't mailing lists that people subscribe/unsubscribe to/from, these are distribution lists, centrally set up and managed. Mailman is overkill I think.

Comment: you can use any subset of features you like - we've used it very effectively for internal distribution lists in non exchange environments. in fact, having internal lists users could control subscription of worked out quite well. you can centrally manage/add/remove addresses without user interaction. If you want really low tech with a small user base, you could always use /etc/aliases... not very scalable, though :)

Answer (score 0):

All of the typical Linux MTAs (Sendmail, Postfix, etc) support simple, administrator-maintained distribution lists.  They're generally called "aliases"; you can see some documentation here:

- For Postfix: http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html
- For Sendmail: http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/doc/op-sh-2.html (look for "The Alias database")

But seriously, do what the other folks suggested and use Mailman.  You get a decent web interface, and you get the ability to accept/reject messages based on a variety of criteria (whereas a simple alias distribution list will allow *anyone* to send mail to the list).

NB: Any of these solutions imply that you're going to be running a mailserver, which may have implications w/r/t your contract, if you're using some sort of hosting company, and also means you need to learn about setting up the appropriate software.